# Is g measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, A)$ be a measurable space and let $f : X \to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function.

Let $g(x) = 0$ if $f(x)$ is rational

and $g(x) = 1$ if $f(x)$ is irrational.

Am I correct in saying $g$ is measurable ?

Comment: You can write $h(a) = \mathbb 1(a\text{ is rational})$, then $g(x)=h(f(x))$, $f$ is measurable and clearly $h$ is measurable too, so $h\circ f$ is measurable. Of course you need to justify that $h$ is measurable.

Comment: How would you prove h to be measurable I know that for h to be measurable it must be a function between two measurable spaces such that the preimage of any measurable set is measurable . @P.Quinton

Comment: Observe that any subset of $\mathbb Q$ is measurable, hence so is $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. For any measurable set $X\subseteq \mathbb R$, the two sets $X\cap \mathbb Q$ and $x\setminus \mathbb Q$ are also measurable and the image of $X$ with respect to $h$ is directly a function of those two sets.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for clarifying and the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse image of any Borel set under $g$ is $\emptyset$, $X$, $f^{-1}(\mathbb  Q)$ or $f^{-1}(\mathbb  Q^{c})$ and each of these sets is measurable.